# How to Checked and Unchecked checkboxes from database using explode implode

Tags: php, mysql, function, mysqli, checkbox

This is a classic problem related to checkboxes, I've tried to find the answer but couldn't. Please help.

I tried to post and edit checkboxes to and from database using php mysqli. Here is what I did.

First, I created connection and save it as **koneksi.php**

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","database_table");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
```

Next I created **profile.php**

```
**// I created a function to call different tables**

function GetCheckboxes($table, $key, $Label, $Nilai='') {
$s = "select * from $table order by id_course";
$r = mysqli_query($con, $s);
 $_arrNilai = explode(',', $Nilai);
  $str = '';
  while ($w = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
    $_ck = (array_search($w[$key], $_arrNilai) === false)? '' : 'checked';
    $str .= "<div>
                <input type='checkbox' name='".$key."[]' value='$w[$key]' 
$_ck>
                $w[$Label]

 </div> ";
  }
  return $str;
}


**// I called the user's checked checkboxes from 'users' table on 'user_course' column **

$sql  = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email='$_SESSION[emailuser]'");
    $r    = mysqli_fetch_array($sql,MYSQLI_BOTH); 


**// and displayed them associated from 'main_course' table. 
//The checkboxes lists are taked from 'main_course' table 
//and the checked value are taken from 'users' table on 'user_course' column**

echo"<label><h4>Course you are applying for:</h4></label>";
$d = GetCheckboxes('main_course', 'course_seo', 'course_name', $r[user_course]);

    echo " $d ";
```

This is my table that I will retrieve my data course from.  In this case, it's the "main_course" table. http://prntscr.com/jjgoqm

And this is the "users" table where I take and save the checkboxes checked value using implode() http://prntscr.com/jjhnu7

And This is the result after checkboxes are selected and saved into the "users" table in the "user_course" column. http://prntscr.com/jjhrbe 
It works on php mysql, but when I changed it into mysqli , it doesn't work and it turned like this http://prntscr.com/jjhv82
It's gone. It worked on mysql but didn't work on mysqli

Please what's going on?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What's `<label><h4>Course you are applying for:</h4></label>";` doing in there?

Comment: Nothing, it's part of my css style. Just the header of checkboxes

Comment: oh sorry if it made you confused, it should be a <? above and followed by echo" so there is the "; after the </label> to close it and begin new php code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see two problems. The first (which is what is most likely causing your code not to work) is that `$con` is out of scope in the `GetCheckboxes` function. You either need to add it as a parameter or add a `global $con;` statement to the start of that function i.e.

```
function GetCheckboxes($table, $key, $Label, $Nilai='') {
  global $con;
  $s = "select * from $table order by id_course";
  $r = mysqli_query($con, $s);
  ...
```

Second (less importantly as it will only cause a `NOTICE` level error), in your call to `GetCheckboxes`, `$r[user_course]` should be `$r['user_course']`.

If you turn on [PHP error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) (`error_reporting(E_ALL);`) you would see the errors that are causing your code not to function.

Comment: Wow Nick, How do you exactly know all those stuff? You just saved my day, Nick. Thank you very much. May God always be with you.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, thanks to Nick, I could make the code work again. I will post the changes for those who want to learn more. Here it is.

```
    **// I created a function to call different tables**

function GetCheckboxes($table, $key, $Label, $Nilai='') {
global $con;
$s = "select * from $table order by id_course";
$r = mysqli_query($con, $s);
 $_arrNilai = explode(',', $Nilai);
  $str = '';
  while ($w = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
    $_ck = (array_search($w[$key], $_arrNilai) === false)? '' : 'checked';
    $str .= "<div>
                <input type='checkbox' name='".$key."[]' value='$w[$key]' 
$_ck>
                $w[$Label]

 </div> ";
  }
  return $str;
}


**// I called the user's checked checkboxes from 'users' table on 'user_course' column **

$sql  = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email='$_SESSION[emailuser]'");
    $r    = mysqli_fetch_array($sql,MYSQLI_BOTH); 


**// and displayed them associated from 'main_course' table. 
//The checkboxes lists are taked from 'main_course' table 
//and the checked value are taken from 'users' table on 'user_course' column**

echo"<label><h4>Course you are applying for:</h4></label>";
$d = GetCheckboxes('main_course', 'course_seo', 'course_name', $r['user_course']);

    echo " $d ";
```